# How can I make my type an instance of Arbitrary?

Tags: haskell, generics, testing, quickcheck

I have the following data and function

```
data Foo = A | B deriving (Show)

foolist :: Maybe Foo -> [Foo]
foolist Nothing  = [A]
foolist (Just x) = [x]

prop_foolist x = (length (foolist x)) == 1
```

when running `quickCheck prop_foolist`, ghc tells me that Foo needs to be an instance of Arbitrary.

```
No instance for (Arbitrary Foo) arising from a use of  ‘quickCheck’
In the expression: quickCheck prop_foolist
In an equation for ‘it’: it = quickCheck prop_foolist
```

I tried `data Foo = A | B deriving (Show, Arbitrary)`, but this results in

```
Can't make a derived instance of ‘Arbitrary Foo’:
  ‘Arbitrary’ is not a derivable class
  Try enabling DeriveAnyClass
In the data declaration for ‘Foo’
```

However, I can't figure out how to enble `DeriveAnyClass`. I just wanted to use quickcheck with my simple function! The possible values of x is Nothing, Just A and Just B. Surely this should be possible to test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two reasonable approaches:

#### Reuse an existing instance

If there's another instance that looks similar, you can *use it*. The `Gen` type is an instance of `Functor`, `Applicative`, and even `Monad`, so you can easily build generators from other ones. This is probably the most important general technique for writing `Arbitrary` instances. Most complex instances will be built up from one or more simpler ones.

```
boolToFoo :: Bool -> Foo
boolToFoo False = A
boolToFoo True = B

instance Arbitrary Foo where
  arbitrary = boolToFoo <$> arbitrary
```

In this case, `Foo` can't be "shrunk" to subparts in any meaningful way, so the default trivial implementation of `shrink` will work fine. If it were a more interesting type, you could have used some analogue of

```
  shrink = map boolToFoo . shrink . fooToBool
```

#### Use the pieces available in `Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary` and/or `Test.QuickCheck.Gen`

In this case, it's pretty easy to just put together the pieces:

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Arbitrary

data Foo = A | B
  deriving (Show,Enum,Bounded)
instance Arbitrary Foo where
  arbitrary = arbitraryBoundedEnum
```

As mentioned, the default `shrink` implementation would be fine in this case. In the case of a recursive type, you'd likely want to add

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
```

and then derive `Generic` for your type and use

```
instance Arbitrary ... where
  ...
  shrink = genericShrink
```

As the documentation warns, `genericShrink` does not respect any internal validity conditions you may wish to impose, so some care may be required in some cases.

---

You asked about `DeriveAnyClass`. If you wanted that, you'd add

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
```

to the top of your file. But *you don't want that*. You certainly don't want it here, anyway. It only works for classes that have a full complement of defaults based on Generics, typically using the `DefaultSignatures` extension. In this case, there is no `default arbitrary :: Generic a => Gen a` line in the `Arbitrary` class definition, and `arbitrary` is mandatory. So an instance of `Arbitrary` produced by `DeriveAnyClass` will produce a *runtime error* as soon as QuickCheck tries to call its `arbitrary` method.